# has ability/ the ability /an ability

Tags: articles

Could you please tell me which one is right?
If none of these sentences is correct, what would be the right sentence?

> 1. She has ability to do it.
> 2. She has an ability to do it.
> 3. She has the ability to do it.
> 4. She has ability of doing it.
> 5. She has an ability of doing it.
> 6. She has the ability of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

"**The ability"** would be the most accurate in this case.

> She has the ability to do it.

'**An** ability' would often be used to describe common case of a particular skill or attribute.

But in this case the word "**She**" makes a particular case for the word '**ability**'.

And about the preposition, 95% of the time it will be the 'ability **to**'.

"ability **to**" is much more natural than "ability **of** doing" something.

If you want the **'of'** preposition, it would be more natural to use the phrase

> 'be **capable OF** doing something'

which is the same in meaning with 'the ability to do something'

Comment: Thank you for your answering. Could you please give me an example of using "an ability"?

Comment: "She has an extraordinary ability in music."
OR
"<Some common skill> looks like it's an ability that everyone has."